# Are there any tools for embedding editable code samples in Canvas?

Tags: lecture-tools

We used to use Repl.it for embedding code in Canvas courses so that students could quickly and easily engage with programming after watching a video or reading content in Canvas. However, they changed their offering and the iframes are no longer editable within Canvas.

We are looking for an alternative tool that would let instructors prepopulate code and then let students modify, compile and run it within a browser. They would all be short code snippets. But it needs to support Python and C/C++.

The only tool we have found so far is Vocareum which looks promising, but I was wondering if anyone knew of any other similar tools we could compare to.

Comment: I don't use Canvas myself, so I have no idea, but I am glad that this question is here.  I hope it will have an answer soon!